# Global variables per session

Tags: c#, session, static, upload, httpresponsemessage

I have a problem dealing with global variables.
I post XML's to my web, it does a POST for each file, in each load valid different fields and store information about it, with the global variables I am storing information of these. When testing from two terminals I realized that static variables are used by both terminals by cleaning each other. What type of variable would you have to use to have information stored for each XML per POST? Thank you.

```
    private static List<RegistroFacturaIN> lstIEntityRegistroFactura = new List<RegistroFacturaIN>();
    private static List<FacturaElectronicaIN> LstFacturaElectronica = new List<FacturaElectronicaIN>(); // Lista de Facturas
    private static List<FacturaAdicional> lstFacAdicional = new List<FacturaAdicional>();
    private static FacturaElectronica IEntity2 = new FacturaElectronica();
    private static List<FacturaAdicional> LstOnlyExcel = new List<FacturaAdicional>();
    private static List<FacturaAdicional> ListExcelOK = new List<FacturaAdicional>();
    private static List<FacturaAdicional> LstFANew = new List<FacturaAdicional>();
    private static int cantRegistrosXML = 0;
    private static int cantRegistrosXMLok = 0;
    private static decimal Importe_Total_Excel = 0;
    private static decimal Importe_Total_Excelok = 0;
    private static int Ejec_CAbecera = 0;
    private static int Planilla = 0;
    private static string Usuario_Red_IAServices = "";
    private static string CDR_IAServices = "";
    private static string Fecha_Inicio_Consulta = ""; // Fecha parametrizada en guia usada para hacer Consultas con el 4004
    private static int XML_Maestro = 0;
    private static string serie = "";
    private static int numeracion = 0;
    private static string totalX = "0";
    private static decimal Importe_Total = 0;
    private static int numerror = 0;
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
        {

            var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

            try
            {...}
         }
    }
```

Comment: A simple dictionary with terminal ID as key would do. But i find your approach a bit strange. Is this a learning project or is this productive?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would I do the dictionary? I do not have DB access. How would you recommend doing this XML load?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Right now it looks like you get it all wrong... If you want something to be "per post" - you shoul use local variables (not static ones") And you should store result of this post "somewhere" (database, memory, cache, etc.)

Comment: Hello Piotr, the functionality is as follows, I have a web where I load XML's when I press the load button I call a js that is in charge of sending me one by one the XML's to my Controller in C #, this one receives each XML by public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile () , Which causes that if I load 10 XML's enter 10 times to my controller, in each entry I am reporting the status of the XML and also storing the important data of these. For that reason I was using static variables.

Comment: Show us the client side code.